# Why is my meta SO rep lower?

Tags: support, meta

At the time of writing, my rep displayed in the header of meta SO is 25, but my rep displayed in normal SO is 27. I have not posted any questions or answers or comments in meta. Why the discrepancy?

**Update:** My meta SO rep has gone up to 27 after posting this question. Coincidence?

Comment: Good things come to those who wait.

Comment: Like the ability to comment on posts that aren't mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It can take up to an hour for your reputation to synchronize between the sites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges.

Your meta account's reputation is synchronized with your main-site rep periodically, but nowhere close to immediately. They're two separate (albeit tightly-linked) accounts, and can become out of sync. Give it a bit of time, and meta should usually catch up with main.